# How to attach EventArgs/custom params when you assign a delegate to the event?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
this.form.Resize += new EventHandler(form_Resize);
```

But I want to assign some objects for later access in the `form_Resize` event, how can I do that?

and do I access the data in the EventArgs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot "assign additional data" to a delegate, but you can create a parameterized version of the `form_Resize` method and then use *lambda expressions* (in C# 3+) or *anonymous delegates* (C# 2+) to specify the additional data when attaching the handler. One way to write this is following:

```
void form_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e, Data additional) {
  // 'additional' contains whatever you specified when attaching handler
}

this.form.Resize += (s, e) => form_Resize(s, e, yourAdditionalData);
```

Comment: +1 - Nice, like the idea of using lambdas for this type of stuff. :)

Answer (score 0):

The data should be part of your form as a field or property.  You don't have the ability to extend the data model in events you don't create.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly do you mean. EventHandler is a predefined delegate type, so two parameters (sender and EventArgs) will be passed automatically in the form_Resize method. From the other hand, you can access all fields of a class where form_Resize method is defined from within form_Resize method itself.

You can read more about EventHandler delegate [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx)